# msbuild - how to modify environment variable for the entire build

Tags: msbuild

I want to modify the environment variable for all `Exec` tasks.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31670922/4784683) seems to imply that it's not possible to do that and [a 2011 blog](http://blog.jdhardy.ca/2011/12/setting-environment-variables-for.html) says outright that it's not possible to change the environment per `Exec` task . . . so does that mean that it's not possible even to set the environment variable for ALL `Exec` tasks globally?

Is this possible? If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: Well if you set the PATH in the shell where you start msbuild then each Exec task gets that PATH. Any reason why you cannot use that? Alternatively you can use a custom task which calls Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable, then the msbuild process' environment gets set while running and any Exec tasks would inherit it. At least that's what I said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803630/set-vcbuild-environment-through-msbuild so I assume it worked for me then, I don't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: @stijn I'm starting `MSBuild` via Visual Studio **build** command.

Comment: That is only partly relevant. If you start devenv.exe from a shell with the proper environment set the effect is the same: the environment propagates to msbuild, then to the cmd.exe processes spawned by it's Exec task. So, same question: can you use that principle or not?

Comment: @stijn I start MSBuild through visual studio `Rebuild` command

Comment: That doesn't matter. MSbuild inherits the environment from VS, no matter what command in the user interface you use.